# Revise the order type of FTS in mysql 5.6 innodb table

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

There are two columns in my table, "date" and "description", i need the result of rows which contain some word in "description" and order by date decreasing, so i add fullindex and run "`alter table order by date decreasing`" first, then run below sql:

```
SELECT date FROM articles WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ('+"big" +"light"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

if the table is MyISAM, the result is order by "date" decreasing, but if the table is InnoDB, the result is automatically sort rows in order of **decreasing relevance**.

i want to use InnoDB table and let the result order by "date" decreasing automatically instead of decreasing relevance, how can i do?

Plus: add the code "order by date desc" to the SQL is workable, but it will cost more time because my tabel have too many lows.

Thank you.

Tommy

Comment: `alter table order by` is a "feature" for MyISAM. It doesn't work for InnoDB. The only way to get something similar would be to use `date` at the primary key. Not that I would suggest that. Or, do it like everyone else does it, and add the `order by` to your query. When comparing the speed, please be aware that every change to your table (e.g. inserts) can destroy the order, so you would have to execute the `alter table` everytime you run your query to be sure that the order is still valid; so when comparing execution time, you will have to include the `alter table order by`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results ordered in some way, you *must* add an `ORDER BY` clause.  Any dependence on default actions will burn you as soon as you delete or update a row.

If you need to discuss this further, provide the entire query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.